# Show that $|\int_C f(z)| \leq 4$

Tags: complex-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$ a real continuous function such that $|f(Z)| \leq 1$ and $C$ the unit circle circulating in the positive directive. Show that $|\int_C f(z)| \leq 4$.**

I know that $|\int_C f(z) dz| \leq  \int_C |f(z)| dz \leq 2 \pi $, but it is not a sufficient bound. Is anyone could help me a this point?

Comment: You may mean the integral $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C f(z)dz$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $r(\theta) := f(e^{i \theta});$ then $r$ has a Fourier expansion of the form $$r(\theta) \sim \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} a_n e^{i n \theta}.$$ Since $r$ is real-valued, $a_{-1} = \overline{a_1}$ and so $|a_{-1}|^2 \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_n|^2.$ Parseval's theorem implies that $$\Big| \int_C f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z \Big|^2 = \Big| \int_0^{2\pi} r(\theta) i e^{i \theta} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \Big|^2 = 4\pi^2 |a_{-1}|^2 \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 4\pi^2 |a_n|^2 = \pi \int_0^{2\pi} |r(\theta)|^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta \le \pi.$$

Comment: Where come from the identity $|a_{-1}|^2 \le \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |a_n|^2$?

Comment: But $\sqrt 2\pi>4$.