# Optimizing a function on the complex unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis, optimization

In my complex class we are given this problem:
Take a continuous function from the complex plane to the real line: $f(z): \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. We also know that $|f(z)| \leq 1$.
Show that $$\bigr| \int_C f(z) dz\bigl| \leq 4$$
Where $C$ is the unit circle.

The way I started this was by saying:
$$\bigr| \int_C f(z) dz\bigl| \leq \int_C |f(z)| dz \leq \int_C dz = \int_{0}^{2 \pi}ie^{i \theta} d{\theta} = 0$$This to me does not seem right, given what I am doing here is actually assuming the function is analytic, which was never given in the problem!

So now I am trying this:
$$sup_{f}\bigr| \int_C f(z) dz\bigl| = sup_{f}\bigr| i\int_{0}^{2\pi} f(e^{i\theta}) e^{i\theta} dz\bigl|$$
While keeping in mind that $|f(z)| \leq 1$ and $f(z): \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

I am however not too sure of how to attack this problem in a smart way, by not just plugging in functions and see what happens.

Thank you for your insight!

Comment: You forgot to put |..| sign around dz in your first attempt, which would have given you $\leq 2\pi$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754708/continuous-function-int-c-fzdz-leq-4

Comment: Also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686432/show-that-int-c-fz-leq-4 (with a different proof).